# MySQL execute function inside query

Tags: mysql

I wrote a mysql query like this

```
select concat(b.functionName,'(',id,')') as outPut from ( SELECT id
FROM   test _table ) a join my_all_functions_table b on a.fID = b.id;
```

What I wanted to do is to execute a function only after fetching its name from table. Function name is stored in `my_all_functions_table` and I fetched that function name and tried to execute the function inside my query. But instead of executing the function, the query returned the function call as a string. i.e. if function name is `func` then it returned `select 'func('id')'` as a string but I expected the function to execute. Can anyone tell what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SET @_query_text = CONCAT('select ', (select concat(b.functionName,'(',id,')') as outPut from ( SELECT id FROM test _table ) a join my_all_functions_table b on a.fID = b.id));

PREPARE qry from @_query_text;

EXECUTE qry;
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm really glad it helped :) Have a nice day.